# Highcharts => How to add ids to the points we push?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm building a line chart and I want my points to have an id. How to do that in using push ?

```
options.series.data.push(data,id); ???
```

or something like that

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want them to have a `ID` in the DOM, e.g. `id="something"`?

Comment: yes exactly in order to be able to do a chart.get()

Comment: Basically I want to do this :
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, {
            y: 216.4,
            id: 'highest'
        }, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

but with a push